# Suggest some ways to communicate (Rx and Tx) between Arduino and LabVIEW through Internet

Tags: ethernet, xbee, esp8266

- Suggest Hardwares to use and also suggest some place to learn about
  IoT, video tutorials, websites, blogs, books etc.
- Currently I am using Xbees to communicate between LabVIEW and Arduino Mega.
- Most of the websites that I checked are using ESP8266 but I am not
  sure how to use them to receive and transmit simultaneously.
  [image][image]

Comment: What type of protocols do you want to run? What is the required bandwidth (message per second, avg message size)? Response time? This could be control algorithm inner time, etc. These types of questions (requirements) need to be answered first before approaching an architecture, design and implementation. You are skipping directly to the implementation.

Comment: I am sending 54 bytes and receiving 18 bytes of data. I want response time to be as minimum as possible, which I think would depend on the internet speed. I am not sure about other things. How would you tackle this problem ? I am asking you to answer your own question :P sorry. I am a newbie.

Comment: Would it work if the round trip of messages is approx. 10-20 ms with a worst case delay of 250 ms? How would the application (LabView/Bot) react? I am assuming that you wish use a WiFi Router. The "Internet Speed" or bit-rate has very little to do with the actual bandwidth as using using WiFi/TCP/IP may require retransmission, etc. If you have requirements of lower than 1 ms it all becomes much more difficult (expensive :).